# UIScrollView not scrolling unless finger is on subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, jailbreak, logos

I am using a UIScrollView to add multiple pages. It is all working fine and the scrolling works, but only if the user scrolls by putting their finger on a subview of the scrollView. This means that if a page has no subviews for instance, it is impossible for the user to scroll, and if the page only has one subview, the user has to put their finger on that subview to scroll. Is there any way I can make it so that the user can scroll by placing their finger anywhere in the scrollView **without** creating a background UIView for the scrollView. Thanks.

Edit: This is the code I'm using:

```
%hook CCUIScrollView
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    %orig;

    [ccView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(pageWidth * 2, pageHeight)];
    [ccView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [ccView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [ccView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}
%end
```

Comment: I'm tweaking the iOS 11 Control Center. I'm accessing the ModuleCollectionView and changing it's contentSize to create a second page, but you can only swipe to this second page when your finger is on a module.

Comment: Here's the code I'm using:

Comment: ```%hook CCUIScrollView
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    %orig;

    [ccView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(pageWidth * 2, pageHeight)];
    [ccView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [ccView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [ccView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}
%end```

Comment: I totally believe you that this is not default behaviour. This is just objective-c using logos to hook into an existing class in iOS and override an existing method. I need to take a look into how apple have formatted this UIScrollView that stops me from scrolling when my finger is not on a subview, thanks.

Comment: Thx, I've added logos as a tag. BTW if this is a jailbreak question you really ought to add that as a tag too, so that folks like me know it's above our pay grade. :)

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help.